# relationship between Gaussian scale and a spatial window

Tags: scale, space, gaussian, windowing

I saw that some works in literature use Gaussian scales in order to determine the size of spatial windows (scale-space). I didn't really understand how we can conclude from one term to another one.
Does somebody know more about that conversion ?